# AWS kinesis producer writing same record multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am writing data to AWS kinesis stream using putRecordsRequest method to write a batch of putRecordsRequestEntryList.
Hence writing is successful but each record is sent multiple times as bellow:

Fetched Record: shardId: shardId-000000000001 partitionKey: 1a9473be8d0ea31f7f79a571bf0db79b sequenceNumber: 49582947864364362927706152534174639194775987182159003666 data: 1522044380916
=>Fetched Record: shardId: shardId-000000000001 partitionKey: 1a9473be8d0ea31f7f79a571bf0db79b sequenceNumber: 49582947864364362927706152534197608785348665205197897746 data: 1522044380916

But when I checked producer log, it was sent for only once.
Any help please...

Comment: Amazon Kinesis is a Distributed Streaming System so it's possible to get record duplicates - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-duplicates.html. Though it's definitely not normal when you're getting a duplicate for each sent record. Maybe you're sending the same request twice when retrying on the error - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-sdk.html#kinesis-using-sdk-java-putrecords? What about sharing the piece of code which is calling the Kinesis API?

Comment: How many producers do you have? What does your code look like? Duplicates can happen, but generally not for each record unless you're doing something wrong. Please show us your code

Comment: "Fetched Record" implies you're reading the stream. If so, are you checkpointing? Please add more detail including sample code for your producer and your consumer. I am inclined to believe you are only writing the record to the stream once, but you're fetching it multiple times because you're not checkpointing.